# how to make UIView animation?

Tags: iphone

I have implemenetd one animation application.In which there is one main view and another is subview in that view.There is also one button.When user touch on that button i want to disply subview with animation.That view must be display from bottom to top.How it possible.I dont know how it possible.

Comment: do you want use [UIView beginAnimations:@"id" context:nil] ? post some code, please.

Comment: yes i want to use beloy type code:
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
 [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:context];
 [UIView setAnimationTransition: UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:thumbnailView cache:NO];
 //[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
 [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
 // self.view.hidden = YES;
 [UIView commitAnimations];

Answer (score 2):

Try the next code:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];

// swap the views and transition
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp 
                       forView:self.view 
                         cache:YES];

[originalSubview removeFromSuperview];
[self.view addSubview:thumbnailView];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```